# How do withdraw or transfer tokens from the custom predefined accounts in a private network?

Tags: polkadot-js, staking, account

I've created a custom network from [node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) with more pallets (staking, babe,...)

I've generated a custom `chain_specs.json` following [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/add-trusted-nodes/)

```
chain_specs.json

{
   ...
   "genesis": {
      ...
      "babe": {
        "authorities": [],
        "epochConfig": {
          "c": [
            1,
            4
          ],
          "allowed_slots": "PrimaryAndSecondaryVRFSlots"
        }
      },
      "grandpa": {
        "authorities": []
      },
      "balances": {
        "balances": [
          [
            "5FHu5erf4YsJknSyX3xanmSyAciZovG5HoZ7Pt4foeFbmtj6",
            1152921504606846976
          ],
          [
            "5CniNy63f1g6u9q7ibiiTJYurSN9SRwxf8TPdYKXMpCjZzsa",
            1152921504606846976
          ]
        ]
      },
      "transactionPayment": {
        "multiplier": "1000000000000000000"
      },
      "session": {
        "keys": [
          [
            "5FHu5erf4YsJknSyX3xanmSyAciZovG5HoZ7Pt4foeFbmtj6",
            "5FHu5erf4YsJknSyX3xanmSyAciZovG5HoZ7Pt4foeFbmtj6",
            {
              "babe": "5FHu5erf4YsJknSyX3xanmSyAciZovG5HoZ7Pt4foeFbmtj6",
              "grandpa": "5EPFfe4wL7ooVaD96e9hFDx1aHjjfRhLtNwoTaS3BgBNTQY9"
            }
          ],
          [
            "5CniNy63f1g6u9q7ibiiTJYurSN9SRwxf8TPdYKXMpCjZzsa",
            "5CniNy63f1g6u9q7ibiiTJYurSN9SRwxf8TPdYKXMpCjZzsa",
            {
              "babe": "5CniNy63f1g6u9q7ibiiTJYurSN9SRwxf8TPdYKXMpCjZzsa",
              "grandpa": "5H4hSLfv45Yf464bPDpvSQzqey3q8dpUhbm3qrWwDtvc8yQL"
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "staking": {
        "validatorCount": 2,
        "minimumValidatorCount": 1,
        "invulnerables": [
          "5FHu5erf4YsJknSyX3xanmSyAciZovG5HoZ7Pt4foeFbmtj6",
          "5CniNy63f1g6u9q7ibiiTJYurSN9SRwxf8TPdYKXMpCjZzsa"
        ],
        "forceEra": "NotForcing",
        "slashRewardFraction": 100000000,
        "canceledPayout": 0,
        "stakers": [
          [
            "5FHu5erf4YsJknSyX3xanmSyAciZovG5HoZ7Pt4foeFbmtj6",
            "5FHu5erf4YsJknSyX3xanmSyAciZovG5HoZ7Pt4foeFbmtj6",
            100000000000000,
            "Validator"
          ],
          [
            "5CniNy63f1g6u9q7ibiiTJYurSN9SRwxf8TPdYKXMpCjZzsa",
            "5CniNy63f1g6u9q7ibiiTJYurSN9SRwxf8TPdYKXMpCjZzsa",
            100000000000000,
            "Validator"
          ]
        ],
        "minNominatorBond": 0,
        "minValidatorBond": 0,
        "maxValidatorCount": null,
        "maxNominatorCount": null
      }
   }
}
```

I've run on 2 VPS and everything works fine, but the problem is I can not transfer or withdraw tokens of the two accounts above (using the [polkadot js extension](https://polkadot.js.org/extension/)).

Does anyone have ideas about this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to go to vanity generator in explorer after starting your private network. Then you need to add secret phase of the keys you have added. After that your account will be added with the exact amount that you have mentioned in your customSpec